# what is the difference between `json.loads()` and `.apply(json.loads)`?

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new to coding, and now I am trying to work on TMDB_5000 dataset from kaggle.

I ran into a problem when trying to deal with json format data like this.

`[{"cast_id": 242, "character": "Jake Sully", "credit_id": "5602a8a7c3a3685532001c9a", "gender": 2, "id": 65731, "name": "Sam Worthington", "order": 0}, {"cast_id": 3, "character": "Neytiri", "credit_i...}]`

I am trying to use `json.loads()` to deal with data, the code is `credits['cast'] = json.loads(credits['cast'])`. But it give me an error like this

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>        in ()
>       ----> 1 credits['cast'] = json.loads(credits['cast'])
>
> ```
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant,
> ```
>
> object_pairs_hook, **kw)
>           346         if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):
>           347             raise TypeError('the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
>       --> 348                             'not {!r}'.format(s.**class**.**name**))
>           349         s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
>           350
>
> ```
> TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Series'
> ```

However, the code `credits['cast'] = credits['cast'].apply(json.loads)`works. So I am very confused, because I think there isn't difference between this two lines of code.

Can anyone explain that to me?

Comment: to make it clear, the cell number 7 works

Comment: when I am trying to load json format data, this one `credits['cast'] = json.loads(credits['cast'])` doesn't work and gives me error"the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'Series'". However, this one works `  `credits['cast'] = credits['cast'].apply(json.loads)`. I don't understand, is there any difference between this two lines of code?

Comment: Will not be good to first load your data and then do panadas operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `credits` variable is a Pandas `DataFrame` and so `credits['cast']` is a `Series`). The `json.loads` function doesn't know how to deal with data types from `pandas`, so you get an error when you do `json.loads(credits['cast'])`.

The `Series` type however has an `apply` method that accepts a function to be called on each value it contains. That's why `credits['cast'].apply(json.loads)` works, it passes `json.loads` as the argument to `apply`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code:

```
credits['cast'] = credits['cast'].apply(json.loads)
```

applies function `json.loads` to each row of `credits['cast']` (each row being a string). The result is a series of decoded objects.

The following code:

```
credits['cast'] = json.loads(credits['cast'])
```

attempts to apply the same function to the Series `credits['cast']`, but the function cannot be applied to a Series.

Comment: Thank you, it is very explicitly explained~

Answer (score 0):

However explanation with great details already been provided, but would like to add in case you are using pandas to read and process data then you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
d_list = [{"cast_id": 242, "character": "Jake Sully", "credit_id": "5602a8a7c3a3685532001c9a", "gender": 2, "id": 65731, "name": "Sam Worthington", "order": 0}, {"cast_id": 3, "character": "Neytiri"}]
```

Create a DataFrame with using `DataFrame.from_dict`

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d_list)
print(df)

cast_id   character                 credit_id  gender       id             name  order
0      242  Jake Sully  5602a8a7c3a3685532001c9a     2.0  65731.0  Sam Worthington    0.0
1        3     Neytiri                       NaN     NaN      NaN              NaN    NaN
```

Another way around which suited for this ppurpose is `pd.read_json` with `orient='records'`.

```
import pandas as pd
d_list = [{"cast_id": 242, "character": "Jake Sully", "credit_id": "5602a8a7c3a3685532001c9a", "gender": 2, "id": 65731, "name": "Sam Worthington", "order": 0}, {"cast_id": 3, "character": "Neytiri", "credit_i...}]
df = pd.read_json(d_list, orient='records')
print(df
```

Comment: You can accept an answer which is really useful in your case by marking  it green beside the answer in left hand side.